# How do I check if _gaq has been emptied?

Tags: google-analytics

GA imposes a rate limit of one-hit-per-second on `ga.js`. If I understand correctly, that means we can `_gaq.push` very fast all we want, but the queue will just keep growing and only get slowly emptied, one event per second.

Suppose I have a button that makes the browser navigate away. If I'm the paranoiac type, how do I ensure that the `_gaq` has been emptied before navigating away (otherwise some events don't get the chance to be sent to GA)?

Comment: What would clearing it do?

Comment: The ga.js rate limit is 10 hits plus one per second -- are you really pushing enough tracking hits to worry about hitting the limit?

Comment: @mike: exactly why I said "[I]f I'm the paranoiac type". To be honest though, I don't know. I'm redesigning the Google Analytics tracking of my web app, and I'm leaving the old tracking in for now so I can have a smooth transition while I fine-tune the new tracking design. That means I'm probably sending about twice as much tracking as I normally would.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility -- with ga.js, you can push a function object onto _gaq, that could be used for page navigation. (*Update: this won't work for detecting rate limiting*)

However... The GA rate limit is for 'hits', i.e. commands sending data to GA. It's not clear how limiting occurs when the limit is reached -- If it's by limiting _gaq command execution then using a function object should work.

Another possibility is to switch to the newer Universal Analytics, which allows for a hitCallback function that runs after the hit has been processed. Also, the rate limit is 20 + 2 hits per second.

---

Update:
I just ran the following test in Chrome, using the developer tools console and network panels:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test', 'test', 'test', i]);
  _gaq.push(function() {console.log(i + ': ' + new Date());});
}
```

The console log shows all 20 timestamps within 1 second.
*The network log only shows the first 10 tracking image requests.*

My interpretation of the test is that GA rate limiting for 'hit' commands works by throwing the data away.

Comment: My understanding is that _gaq should really be a FIFO queue. What the documentation says about the rate limit, I take it to mean that only event type hits will deplete the quota; all other hit types will not deplete the quota when encountered. If that's the case, then your suggestion will probably work.

Comment: Bad news... from the test I just ran, it looks like when the GA rate limit is reached, data isn't queued up but thrown away.

Comment: Shouldn't that be considered a bug? I don't know about other people, but if I am forced to lose data, I would rather lose data at the end than be missing chunks in the middle.

Comment: It's not a bug, but the GA docs might be clearer on the point. The docs say "[when] the maximum limit has been reached ... no new requests are sent". It doesn't say anything about queuing up hits.

Comment: But then what does the 'q' in `_gaq` stand for? :S